# How to handle OIDC Server being down from ASP.Net Core application

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application configured to use OIDCAuthentication, as follows:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = appSettings.OIDCAuthority;
                    options.ClientId = appSettings.OIDCClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = appSettings.OIDCClientSecret;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                        {
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
```

Note I have hooked in to the `OnRemoteFailure` and `OnAuthenticationFailed` events, with breakpoints on each of those handlers.

I am trying to figure out how to handle the scenario in which the OIDC Server is down.  So I'm simulating this in my local debug environment by NOT running the Identity Server project.  When the .Net Core application redirects to the OIDC server for authentication, the user is presented with this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I understand why that Exception is being thrown, but I am unclear as to how to handle it so as to display a more friendly error to the user.  I guess I could do this in a more global exception handler? (still have to look into that), but I would expect that **at least one of the above-mentioned breakpoints should be hit though?**  Any ideas as to why they would NOT be hit?  Surely this scenario qualifies as a `OnRemoteFailure` event?

Comment: Was my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there are many error sources that we have to deal with.

If you try to login (challenge) the first thing that will happen is that the [HandleChallengeAsyncInternal](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs,6e7122af7a87af50,references) method is called and it will try to download the discovery document from your identity server.

For this initial request there is no error handling, so what you need to do here is to capture that exception in a custom ErrorHandlerMiddleware in your request pipeline and for exceptions from that code, then redirect the user to a suitable "can't login error page".

For example, in the Startup class, add this middleware:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
        {
            ExceptionHandler = new OAuthExceptionMiddleware(env).Invoke
        });
```

Then check if the source is from IdentiytModel and if so redirect to some other page, like this sample code:

```
public class OAuthExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public OAuthExceptionMiddleware(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;

        if (ex == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(ex.Source== "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols")
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/AuthError", false);
        else
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error", false);
    }
}
```